# Client Server approach for Android application

Tags: android, google-app-engine, gwt, requestfactory

I currently have a working implementation using GAE and servlets to communicate with my android application.  The app will create json objects and send/receive them using the httpclient.  I then was looking at the 2.4 beta plugin for using C2DM and noticed that they use GWT along with a RequestFactory for communication.  I was wondering if this approach is worth the time switching? Is it easy to setup and configure? Seems like this would be a nice approach if i want to say develop a mobile site along with the app?

Comment: Would you consider writing a Python version of the app to run in parallel?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `C2DM` you will need your users to use a google account. I personally don't feel 100% confortable with that.

The best thing about C2DM is that you avoid polling your GAE server. If you have an already working solution, why would you change it?

Comment: 99% of Android users already have Google accounts, because they have Google experience devices.

Comment: yes, until amazon app-store come along which does not support google-lock-in-service like C2DM, LVL and google pay api. Don't worry Nick, I still like appengine and android tho :) Please just don't do too much vendor lock in stuff ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend android - appengine combination. However if you want your app to be on non google-play device, you need to think around C2DM/LVL or google wallet API(a mandatory on google play). RequestFactory is great but it is tightly coupled, imho. I would recommend Rest which is platform agnostic, very loosely coupled, thus support GWT, android, iOS, BlackBerry, WebOS, desktop ...